# Add required validator for htmleditor field in exts?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Please let me know how to add required validation check to 'htmleditor' field in extjs, allowBlank:false is not working.

Comment: Which version are you using because you have 4.1 and 4.2 tags. 4.2 is in beta as of now.

Answer (score 0):

In Ext 4.1.3 Documentation, there is no such config like 'allowBlank' for `Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor`.

So one way to check htmleditor has value or not is by using `getValue()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Avinash T. , can you please tell me how to render the error(error icon with tooltip error message) thru code similar to allowBlank:false, code will be of great help.

Comment: @Shan `markInvalid()` is only visual and get overridden when any validation runs. It will never cause the form to be invalid.